# bottom tab change fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I've been trying to change my fragment when changing the tab and I don't know why it isn't working, I've checked many video but it's still not working, I don't know what my mistake is if you could kindly point it out ( I've tried the get support fragment as well but it doesn't work as well it just goes red) , here is my code

```
package com.example.whatsoever.ttravel;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.view.MenuItem;

//import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
//import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener 
mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:

                category_map map = new category_map();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.beginTransaction(R.id.a,map,map.getTag()).commit();


               return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:

                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

 }
```

here us my xml file where I want to add my fragments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is an image of the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up40m.png)

please help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass arguments into the `beginTransactions()` method. This method doesn't take any parameters, you can see that here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#begintransaction

Try this line `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().commit();` And see if it compiles. What you probably want to do is pass in those parameters to the fragment, or you are looking for another transaction method on the fragment transaction called replace:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction#replace

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
```

with below

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
```